# X3DOM disable keyboard shortcuts

Tags: shortcut, x3d, x3dom

I want to disable the keyboard shortcuts of a x3dom scene(e.g. press 'r' to reset view or press 'd' to show/hide stats. I need this because i'm implementing keysensor through javascript. I think that i have to add something after

Answer (score 0):

http://x3dom.org/docs/dev/configuration.html
All answers here... you'll need to use tag .